# Shortcut for commenting CSS in VS 2008

Tags: css, visual-studio

When I press the standard Ctrl + E, C (an other variants) in VS2008 whilst editing a CSS file, it says that command is not available. How do I setup a shortcut to apply a plain old /* */ comment to selected text in VS? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within Visual Studio, hit Alt-F11 to open the Macro IDE and add a new module by right-clicking on MyMacros and selecting Add|Add Module...

Paste the following in the source editor:

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module CommentCSS
    Sub CommentCSS()
        Dim selection As TextSelection
        selection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection

        Dim selectedText As String
        selectedText = selection.Text

        If selectedText.Length > 0 Then
            selection.Text = "/*" + selectedText + "*/"
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

You can create a keyboard shortcut by going to Tools|Options... and selecting **Keyboard** under the **Environment** section in the navigation on the left.  Select your macro and assign any shortcut you like.

You can also add your macro to a menu or toolbar by going to Tools|Customize... and selecting the **Macros** section in the navigation on the left.  Once you locate your macro in the list, you can drag it to any menu or toolbar, where it its text or icon can be customized to whatever you want.

Comment: Wow, I thought Ctrl + K, Ctrl + C would do it. Anyone know why this this doesn't work in CSS? Works in html, C#, SQL, Javascript...

Comment: This is great - tjere's just one other thing - when commenting more than 1 line of CSS, it seems to add an extra tab to the beginning of every line after the first one? The result is your code is tabbed in like an upside down staircase. Why would it be doing this?

Comment: @wows - I can't reproduce what you are describing; commenting seems to work the same whether I have one or many lines of CSS selected.  The formatting doesn't change at all.

Comment: @Jeff Hillman - I figured it out - it was because VS was set to "Block" indenting instead of "Smart" indenting under CSS specific editor settings. Switching to smart fixes the problem. Cheers!

Comment: @wows - Glad to hear it.  It might be possible to modify this for "Block" mode on by inserting '/*' and '*/' directly into the text (using selection.AnchorPoint.AbsoluteCharOffset and selection.ActivePoint.AbsoluteCharOffset) rather than replacing the entire selection.  Something to try later.

Comment: a more advanced solution with: 1. support for undo, 2. handling all file types with a single keyboard shortcut, 3. handling of uncommenting. is shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110429/in-visual-studio-2010-is-there-a-way-to-easily-comment-out-lines-in-css

Answer (score 0):

here's an even simpler solution:

```
Sub CommentCSS()
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine(VsStartOfLineOptions.VsStartOfLineOptionsFirstText)
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "/*"
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine()
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "*/"
End Sub
```

you can record it yourself using ctrl+shift+R

1. place the cursor on the line you want to comment
2. press "Home" on your keyboard
3. type /*
4. press "End" on your keyboard
5. type */
6. save your recording

Comment: Thanks, but this only really works for one line at a time. It's quite common to comment a whole CSS class or multiple classes/selectors at a time.