# Shortcut for uncommenting CSS in VS 2008?

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, editor

I used the macro mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248900/shortcut-for-commenting-css-in-vs-2008) to comment a text selection in the CSS editor in VS 2008.  I am looking for another macro which uncomments comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a similar module/method, I think that should work, I haven't tried, but this is what I think.
Please consider this as addition to the post that you have linked, you can look for the other details from that post.

```
Public Module UnCommentCSS
    Sub UnCommentCSS()
        Dim selection As TextSelection
        selection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection

        Dim selectedText As String
        selectedText = selection.Text

        If selectedText.Length > 0 _
           and selectedText.StartsWith("/*") _
           and selectedText.EndsWith("*/") Then
           selectedText = selectedText.Split("*"c)
           selection.Text = selectedText(1)
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Note: this works if you have no nested * in between /* */
Otherwise you have to make necessary improvements/changes

Answer (score 0):

As Brian Schmitt of IObservable [suggests](http://www.brianschmitt.com/2009/09/how-to-comment-uncomment-code-selection.html), you could use the same key to comment and uncomment your code, depending of course on whether or not it's already commented.  The code he uses to achieve this is the following:

```
Sub CommentCSS()
If Not DTE.ActiveDocument.Name.EndsWith("css") Then Return
 Try
  DTE.UndoContext.Open("Comment CSS")

  Dim txtSel As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
  Dim currText As String = txtSel.Text

  If currText.Length > 0 Then
   Dim newTxt As String
   If currText.Trim.StartsWith("/*") AndAlso currText.Trim.EndsWith("*/") Then
    newTxt = currText.Replace("/*", "").Replace("*/", "")
   Else
    newTxt = "/*" + currText + "*/"
   End If

   txtSel.Delete()
   txtSel.Insert(newTxt, vsInsertFlags.vsInsertFlagsInsertAtEnd)
  End If
 Finally
  DTE.UndoContext.Close()
 End Try
End Sub
```

I removed his comments from the code as they messed up SO's code coloring, but the option that he gives seems pretty convenient.  Also, in the link provided above, he explains all about how to bind the shortcut keys to make it work right.