# In Visual Studio 2010, is there a way to easily comment out lines in CSS?

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Does anybody know if there is a way in Visual Studio 2010 to highlight and comment out lines in CSS files like you can with all other files (by clicking a button)? Perhaps a Visual Studio extension? Commenting them manually is cumbersome.

Comment: ctrl-k-ctrl-c doesn't work? (I haven't used it for CSS files specifically, so don't know if it works there)

Comment: +! Good point - I never noticed this, CTRL+K+C doesn't work and there is no menu option to comment-out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately the regular commands for commenting and uncommenting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) don't work for CSS. Instead, you'll need to record or write a macro that does this and attach it to your own shortcut.

To comment the selected text (note, this is quick and dirty and therefore comments it as a single block):

```
Sub CssComment()
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "/*" + DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text + "*/"
End Sub
```

**Update**
This new one below works more like the regular comment command and comments on a line-by-line basis. It means you don't have to select the text before hand. This also does all the changes as a single undoable operation and checks the file extension so that you can assign this to the regular shortcut and it will work for all files.

```
Sub CommentCss()
    Dim ts1 As TextSelection = CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection(), EnvDTE.TextSelection)

    Dim fileName = DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName

    ' We should default to regular commenting if we're not editing CSS.
    ' This allows this macro to be attached to the Ctrl+K+C shortcut
    ' without breaking existing file format commenting.
    If Not fileName.EndsWith(".css") Then
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.CommentSelection")
        Return
    End If

    Dim weOpenedUndo As Boolean = False
    If Not DTE.UndoContext.IsOpen Then
        DTE.UndoContext.Open("CommentCSS")
        weOpenedUndo = True
    End If

    ts1.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstColumn, True)
    Dim ep1 As EditPoint2 = ts1.TopPoint.CreateEditPoint()
    Dim ep2 As EditPoint2 = ts1.BottomPoint.CreateEditPoint()

    While ep1.Line <= ep2.Line
        Dim text As String = ep1.GetLines(ep1.Line, ep1.Line + 1)
        text = text.Trim()

        If Not text.StartsWith("/*") Or Not text.EndsWith("*/") Then
            ep1.StartOfLine()
            ep1.Insert("/*")
            ep1.EndOfLine()
            ep1.Insert("*/")
        End If
        Dim lineBeforeDown As Integer = ep1.Line
        ep1.LineDown()

        If ep1.Line = lineBeforeDown Then
            Exit While
        End If
    End While

    ts1.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstColumn, True)

    If weOpenedUndo Then
        DTE.UndoContext.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

**Update for Uncommenting**
This macro performs the reverse task. Again, it's implemented so that it will work for all documents if required by checking the file extension and deferring to the standard `Edit.UncommentSelection` command for non-CSS files.

```
Sub UncommentCss()
    Dim ts1 As TextSelection = CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection(), EnvDTE.TextSelection)
    Dim ep1 As EditPoint2 = ts1.TopPoint.CreateEditPoint()
    Dim ep2 As EditPoint2 = ts1.BottomPoint.CreateEditPoint()

    Dim fileName = DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName

    ' We should default to regular commenting if we're not editing CSS.
    ' This allows this macro to be attached to the Ctrl+K+C shortcut
    ' without breaking existing file format commenting.
    If Not fileName.EndsWith(".css") Then
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.UncommentSelection")
        Return
    End If

    Dim weOpenedUndo As Boolean = False
    If Not DTE.UndoContext.IsOpen Then
        DTE.UndoContext.Open("UncommentCSS")
        weOpenedUndo = True
    End If

    While ep1.Line <= ep2.Line
        ep1.StartOfLine()

        Dim text As String = ep1.GetLines(ep1.Line, ep1.Line + 1)
        text = text.Trim()

        If text.StartsWith("/*") And text.EndsWith("*/") Then
            Dim epEndOfLine As EditPoint2 = ep1.CreateEditPoint()
            epEndOfLine.EndOfLine()
            text = text.Substring(2, text.Length - 4)
            ep1.ReplaceText(epEndOfLine, text, vsEPReplaceTextOptions.vsEPReplaceTextKeepMarkers Or vsEPReplaceTextOptions.vsEPReplaceTextAutoformat)
        End If

        Dim lineBeforeDown As Integer = ep1.Line
        ep1.LineDown()

        If ep1.Line = lineBeforeDown Then
            Exit While
        End If
    End While

    ts1.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstColumn, True)

    If weOpenedUndo Then
        DTE.UndoContext.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

**Update 18Oct2012**
As per [dirq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7889841/23234), there is an extension, [Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f) that provides CSS commenting and uncommenting. I would recommend using this over the macros above as it provides other great support besides just the CSS commenting shortcuts.

Comment: CTRL+K+C and CTRL+K+U doesn't work. Could you elaborate on the macro?

Comment: @Jeff Sweet! Seems like it would be pretty easy, but I'll let you prove it. :-D

Comment: @jeremcc: No problem. I'll update my answer with a better macro when I've worked it out.

Comment: @jeremcc: Updated to include better comment macro and to include an uncomment counterpart.

Comment: @jeremcc: You're welcome. It was an interesting exercise to work on. I learned quite a bit about the Visual Studio object model.

Comment: Great answer, makes all the difference that you check the file type so you can use the same shortcut :) and no problems with the format staying the same when you uncomment either, nice job +1

Answer (score 9):

There's an extension available that works better than the macro: Web Essentials.  Check it out. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f